# Why doesn’t using a missing package cause Visual Studio to complain about my Azure Function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, using

I’m new to C#. In my project, I have a file which contains this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyNamespace {
    public static class MyClass {
        // ...

        static MyClass () {
            // ...
        }

        [FunctionName("...")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log) {

            log.LogInformation("...");
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

For all those `using` statements, I have a corresponding package listed under **Solution explorer** → **Dependencies** → **Packages**, except for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. Now, Visual Studio doesn’t complain about this fact and the build process works just fine. Running the application, however, this error appears when it reaches the `log.LogInformation("...")` statement:

[image]

So, I install it from NuGet:

[image]

but doing that, I obtain a different error from the console of the Azure Function, that is:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: What framework is your function running on? Netcore 2.2 or 3? If it's 3, make sure the logging package is the 2.x variant. Also make sure you have the updated Azure Functions sdk and visual studio templates associated

Comment: The settings are **.NET Core 2.1** as target framework and **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.7**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed dependent packages like Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions. Its strange by default dependent packages are installed as part of creating new Azure function. I would suggest try once again using Visual studio template of Azure function.